# OPC UA: Calling method Sinumerik

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm trying to call this method using OPCFoundation library. To select a program

Methods:

[image]

```
NodeId node = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/Filehandling");
NodeId method = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/Filehandling/Select");
object[] argument = new object[2];

argument[0] = new NodeId("ns=2;s=Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program/EXAMPLE.MPF");
argument[1] = channel;

var result = _session.Call(node, method, argument);
```

But it's throwing the excepcion:

```
 BadNodeIdUnknown
```

And I checked that node exists.

I don't know what nodeId i have to use as objectId argument of Call method.

Comment: Yeah, this is not always so clear. It should refer to the object that is the target of the method call. Probably something above Methods in your structure.

Comment: @JouniAro I already called other methods like CopyFileToServer and I can use the nodeId "/Method" as objectId and "/Method/CopyFileToServer" as methodId. And it worked without any problem.

Comment: OK, then you will have to check it from the server manufacturer, what they are expecting in this case.